# How to add a template footer to all pages in wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

What I am trying to achieve is can I have selected code added to a template of sorts so that I can call it later, as I want to have this code on all of my pages at the bottom so that I don't need to edit it 6 or 7 times dependent on the amount of pages I have. e.g. see my front page .. [homepage](http://www.scottiescotsman.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put it inside your `footer.php` and call [`get_footer()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/) where you want to include it or use [`get_template_part()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/).

Comment: my footer is fixed but the content i don't need it in the footer i need it in the <?php get_template_part(??); ?> ihave already tried this method and failed.

Comment: I have since worked it out. I added a file called Secondfooter.php with the intended code inside and then just called the <?php get_template_part( 'Secondfooter' ); ?> where ever I want the code inserted.